# Can I use DropDownListFor in a WebGrid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid, html.dropdownlistfor

My problem seems to be the Html.DropDownLisTFor helper uses the page model, not the current row item. Is there a way around this?

This is my viewmodel:

```
 public class DropTest
    {
        public IEnumerable<DropQuestion> DropQuestions { get; set; }
    }
    public class DropQuestion
    {
        public Int32? QuestionNo { get; set; }
        public Int32? Status { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> IStatuses { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is the view I want:

```
@model Blah.ViewModels.DropTest   
@{

    var DGrid = new WebGrid(Model.DropQuestions);
}

@DGrid.GetHtml(
columns: DGrid.Columns(

    DGrid.Column("QuestionNo", "Question No"),
//I need this to work picking up the correct status for the current row??
    DGrid.Column("Status", "StatusFor",
        format: @<text>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Status, Model.IStatuses)
   `     </text>),
         )))
```

I can use DropDownList but this doesn't correctly assign "Selected"

Thanks in advance for any advice.

My problem was fixed by adding a temporary type to the model and assigining it the Status value in another column. This could be improved by doing all the work in one column by I couldn't figure out how without getting errors??
My ViewmModel has now had this amendment:

```
public class DropTest
{
    public IEnumerable<DropQuestion> DropQuestions { get; set; }
    public Int32 GridStatus { get; set; }
}
```

and the view:

```
DGrid.Column("QuestionNo", "Question No",
         format: ((item) => { Model.GridStatus = item.Status ?? 0; return item.QuestionNo; } )),
DGrid.Column("Status", "StatusFor",
        format: @<text>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.GridStatus, Model.IStatuses)
        </text>),
```

Hope this helps someone or could even be improved to perfection by someone else!

Comment: I found this by searching around. I don't have time to try it out, but maybe it'll help you: http://www.seanrowland.com/?p=69

Comment: Thanks @Splendor :-) Basically I added a new temporary variable to the model called GridStatus and use that instead of Status. Within any column in the grid it has to be assigned to item.Status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I added a new temporary variable to the model called GridStatus and use that instead of Status. Within any column in the grid it has to be assigned to item.Status